# pydotplus.graphviz.InvocationException: GraphViz's executables not found

Tags: python, decision-tree

I tried to run this but I am getting GraphViz's executables not found. I have done pip install graphviz but no success

```
import pandas
from sklearn import tree
import pydotplus
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as pltimg

df = pandas.read_csv("shows.csv")

d = {'UK': 0, 'USA': 1, 'N': 2}
df['Nationality'] = df['Nationality'].map(d)
d = {'YES': 1, 'NO': 0}
df['Go'] = df['Go'].map(d)

features = ['Age', 'Experience', 'Rank', 'Nationality']

X = df[features]
y = df['Go']

dtree = DecisionTreeClassifier()
dtree = dtree.fit(X, y)
data = tree.export_graphviz(dtree, out_file=None, feature_names=features)
graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(data)
graph.write_png('mydecisiontree.png')

img=pltimg.imread('mydecisiontree.png')
imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

Comment: `pip install graphviz` just installs the Python module.  The actual GraphViz program is something you have to download from graphviz.org and install separately.

Comment: Thank you very much. I installed graphviz but I am getting an error format "png" not recognized